# Passenger application error: Internal error

Tags: python, django, passenger, web-hosting

I am trying to migrate my Python Django web app on hosting from the local environment. The installation went well, but at the end I do not see the starting page for Django here staging.changerz.education. In the logs I found the error and not sure what is a problem that I need to fix in my app. Please, help anyone:

```
   "error" : {
      "category" : "INTERNAL_ERROR",
      "id" : "23a01cfb",
      "problem_description_html" : "<p>The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application. But the application itself (and not Passenger) encountered an internal error.</p><p>The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:</p><pre>Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File &quot;/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py&quot;, line 369, in &lt;module&gt;\n    app_module = load_app()\n  File &quot;/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py&quot;, line 76, in load_app\n    return imp.load_source(&apos;passenger_wsgi&apos;, startup_file)\n  File &quot;/var/www/u1115154/data/www/staging.changerz.education/passenger_wsgi.py&quot;, line 6, in &lt;module&gt;\n    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\n  File &quot;/var/www/u1115154/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py&quot;, line 1, in &lt;module&gt;\n    from django.utils.version import get_version\n  File &quot;/var/www/u1115154/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py&quot;, line 71, in &lt;module&gt;\n    @functools.lru_cache()\nAttributeError: &apos;module&apos; object has no attribute &apos;lru_cache&apos;\n</pre>",
      "solution_description_html" : "<p class=\"sole-solution\">Unfortunately, Passenger does not know how to solve this problem. Please try troubleshooting the problem by studying the <strong>error message</strong> and the <strong>diagnostics</strong> reports. You can also consult <a href=\"https://www.phusionpassenger.com/support\">the Passenger support resources</a> for help.</p>",
      "summary" : "The application process exited prematurely."
   },
```

Comment: I think you may need to provide more info on the platform. My guess is that you are missing an environment variable being loaded. Try using the `python manage.py runserver` command in your project folder to see if you get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: The thing is that on the local environment I don't get any errors: `(myenvnew) elenaorlova@Elenas-MacBook-Air myenvnew % python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 28, 2021 - 00:39:53
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'gamechangers.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that the Python version was different from what I have in the virtual environment, so it is worth checking the Python version on the hosting provider side.